Keycode-logger for usb for HORI racing wheel
Ok so i am trying to find a way of making my pi pico emulate the brakes on my racing sim so i can make a handheld brake and i figured out how to make it send keycodes but how do i log the usb port so i can log the keycode the brakes are giving and then setting it in my circuitpython program on the pi pico?
here is my circuitpython code if it helps:
import board
import time
import digitalio
import usb_hid
from adafruit_hid.keyboard import Keyboard

kbd = Keyboard(usb_hid.devices)

button = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.GP18)  # Replace with the pin connected to your button
button.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
button.pull = digitalio.Pull.UP

while True:
    if not button.value:
        print("d")
        kbd.press(0x14)  # Replace with the key code for the brake pedal (e.g. 'B' key)
    else:
        print("u")
        kbd.release(0x14)




Sorry for the spelling mistakes i am not good at english.
any help will be appreciated.
thanks in advance
i have tried this code but i want more a program if that exist:
import usb_hid
from adafruit_hid.keyboard import Keyboard

kbd = Keyboard(usb_hid.devices)

print("Press the brake pedal...")
while True:
    key_code = kbd.keycode_read()
    if key_code:
        print(f"Key code: {key_code}")
        break

